# Can I run Steam games through WINE with native Steam?

Tags: steam, linux, wine

All tutorials I see on running Steam games through WINE require Steam to be installed using WINE. I use the native version of Steam, as in the official Linux version.

Is there any way I can run Steam games through WINE if I didn't install Steam itself through PlayOnLinux or WINE?

My OS is Ubuntu 14.04 and my environment is GNOME 3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes and no.

First of all: This is not directly related to any game, so you're better off at a Linux forum for help. I recommend you the most popular Linux subreddits on reddit.

## 1. No ...

... it's not possible in a very convenient way. And to say this at the beginning, you're really better off having a native Steam and a WINE Steam and switch between them when you need either of it.

## 2. Yes, you can!

Ok, there is a way to do it like you want it. There's a GitHub project called [SteamBridge](https://github.com/sirnuke/steambridge) which lets you start WINE Steam games per native Steam. AFAIK you can also use Steam overlay from the native one.

The downside is that as it uses a custom Steam DLL, this clearly breaks the Steam TOS. So especially if you do competitive online-gaming **do not use this** as this **may** lead to a VAC ban.

Some users report that they use this a couple of time and never got problems with it, other state they got banned because of it.

You may try it, but I warned you.

Comment: i saw steambridge, but the possible VAC is too scary for me. i'll just use a WINE steam.

Comment: As I said, for now this is the only method to combine native/WINE Steam. :C

Comment: One issue with wine steam is the lack of big picture mode which is necessary for the steam controller to work properly in most cases